# Running STGeomFromText from within access gives "Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in query expression"?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sqlgeography

The following code runs on a button on a form that I click and every time the button is clicked it stops at the recordset line with:

> Syntax Error (Missing Operator) in query expression
> 'geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-95.3098 29.8131)', 4326)'

I can't figure out what it is referring to. When I copy and paste the query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it runs fine.

```
Dim GC As String
GC = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-95.3098 29.8131)', 4326)")(0).Value
```

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server **and** MS Access... can you explain why?

Comment: That is a SQLServer function - AFAIK, Access will not recognize. If your data is in SQLServer backend, try a pass-through query.